# .Net encryption and java decryption with RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding

Tags: c#, java, encryption

we have existing encryption code in java and which is working absolutely fine.I am trying to create same encryption method in .net which is failing java decryption method saying bad padding exception. See the code details below:
Working Java Code:
Encryption:

```
private static byte[] doThis(String message) {
    byte[] messageCrypte = null;
       try {
        // Certificate Input Stream
        // LA SSL Certificate to be passed.
        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(certificate);

        // X509Certificate created
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
        inStream.close();

        // Getting Public key using Certficate
        PublicKey rsaPublicKey = (PublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();

        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "SunJCE");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaPublicKey);

        byte[] messageACrypter = message.getBytes();
        // Encrypted String
        messageCrypte = encryptCipher.doFinal(messageACrypter);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: Exception Handling
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    return messageCrypte;
}
```

Equivalent c# .Net code I am trying to use but I am getting bad padding exception form java decryption code.

```
    static byte[] doThis(string message)
    {
        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(@"C:\Data\abc-rsa-public-key-certificate.cer");
        byte[] aa = cert.GetPublicKey();

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
        byte[] Exponent = { 1, 0, 1 };

        RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
        //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = aa;
        //RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent;
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
        byte[] bb = RSA.Encrypt(GetBytes(message), false);
        return bb;
    }
```

**Java code for decryption**

```
private String getDecryptedString(byte[] credentials, PrivateKey secretKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {
        String decryptedString;
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "SunJCE");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] messageDecrypte = decryptCipher.doFinal(credentials);
        decryptedString = new String(messageDecrypte);
        return decryptedString;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your java decryption code ? and show where you get error it will may help to solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure (= do you _know_) .net/C# uses the _same_ padding?

Comment: `message.getBytes();` <--- **NEVER** do this. You have no control over the charset used to obtain the bytes of the string. This alone could be the source of your problem - find out what charset the equivalent `GetBytes` method uses in your C# code and [enforce this in your Java code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: Here is my java decryption code:

Comment: I just want to note that your encryption is very weak. ECB mode sucks and without a MAC you're vulnerable to padding oracle attacks.

Comment: I am not sure about this  "Are you sure (= do you know) .net/C# uses the same padding? "  one of the sites have suggested this so tried with this option but did not work though.

Comment: Hi All any help on this?

Comment: Right answer:        public static string EncrypIt(string inputString, X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaservice = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
            byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
            byte[] ciphertext = rsaservice.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
            string cipherresult = Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext);
            return cipherresult;                 
        }

Answer (score 1):

Here is the .net code:

```
public static string EncrypIt(string inputString, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaservice = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
    byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
    byte[] ciphertext = rsaservice.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
    string cipherresult = Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext);
    return cipherresult;                 
}
```